# Custom Blender Python icons with adjustable colours

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I am writing a Blender add-on and I want to add a custom icon into the UI panel.

I can do this with `bpy.utils.previews`, but it seems to only want PNG files so if I design the icon to be white it looks good in dark mode but becomes invisible if the user sets the Blender theme to light mode. Is it possible to use a custom icon as an svg so that it always uses the right colour, like the default icons do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a very good question. There is [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.icons.html) I think they can be made from .blend files containing geometry. No idea how to use them, because they don't seem to be documented very well. [This](https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/2.80/python_api/ui_design/) seems to be related.